# form post back related

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

I have one form with submit button in asp.net and C#. Form is for submitting comment to website webmaster through email. C# code is as below.

but facing one problem. i.e. on refreshing the page it again sends the comment in email due to postback. How can I avoid this? here is the code...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            string body = "";
            //body = body + "<html><head></head><body>";

            body = body + "Dear Balvignan Team,\r\n";

            if (txtComment.Text != null)
            {
                body = body + "Comment: " + txtComment.Text;
            }



            if (SendEmail(txtEmail.Text.Trim(), "Comment", body, false) == true)
            {

                lblContactAcknowledge.Text = "Thank You For <br />Submitting comment.";

                lblContactAcknowledge.Visible = true;
                PnlTalkToUs.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                lblContactAcknowledge.Visible = false;
                PnlTalkToUs.Visible = true;
            }

    }
```

SendEmail is function to send email.

Comment: Check for (!isPostBack) in Page Load, thats it.

Answer (score 0):

**In your page_load event**

```
if(page.isPostback==NO)
{
    //send an email
}
else
{
   //Don't send
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Page.IsPostBack Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) to check, if its a Postback or page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the following option:

```
  if (SendEmail(txtEmail.Text.Trim(), "Comment", body, false) == true)
            {
               Response.Redirect("contact.aspx?success=true");
             }
          else
          {
              Response.Redirect("contact.aspx");
          }
```

On Page Load

```
if (!Page.IsPostback)
{
   if (Request.QueryString["success"] == "true" )
   {
      lblContactAcknowledge.Text = "Thank You For <br />Submitting comment.";

      lblContactAcknowledge.Visible = true;
      PnlTalkToUs.Visible = false;
   }
   else
   {
      lblContactAcknowledge.Visible = false;
      PnlTalkToUs.Visible = true;
   }
}
```

When the user refreshes the page (ctrl + r, f5, etc) will to a GET request, not a POST request.

**EDIT another solution**

Another solution is to use ViewState:

```
 public bool EmailSent
        {
            get
            {
                return ViewState["EmailSent"] != null ? (bool)ViewState["EmailSent"] : false;
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["EmailSent"] = value;
            }
        }


protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        ....
        if (!EmailSent)
        {

           if (SendEmail(txtEmail.Text.Trim(), "Comment", body, false) == true)
           {       
              ... 
              EmailSent = true;
           }
           else
           {
              ...
           }
        }
}
```

Comment: any other solution without query string parameter?

Comment: @hetalgala, I added another solution